# can't unlink image which is in url format

Tags: php, file, unlink, getcwd

php is getting image in following format, while echoing `$_POST['img']`

```
http://localhost/uploads/images/1533033949-8.jpg
```

But why unlink doesn't working -

```
// Get src.
$img = $_POST["img"];

// Check if file exists.
if (file_exists(getcwd() . $img)) {
  // Delete file.
  unlink(getcwd() . $img);
  echo "Deleted";
}
```

I tried testing directly, but doesn't work

```
unlink($img)
```

Comment: Does the file exist at  `getcwd() . $img` ? Have you printed that out to see what it looks like? And do you/your script/your server have permissions to unlink a file?

Comment: `unlink` works on the file system, not with HTTP URLs. And appending `http://localhost/uploads/images/1533033949-8.jpg` to the current working directory is very unlikely to give you a proper file system path.

Comment: The manual on `getcwd()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php **explicitly** states: *"Returns the current working **directory** on success, or FALSE on failure."**, not a URL. Plus `The above example will output something similar to:

/home/didou
/home/didou/cvs`. So look at the URL you get now; not the same right? There you go, *wink*.

Comment: converting url information in variable using `substr, strlen` works.

Answer (score 2):

> unlink works on the file system, not with HTTP URLs. And appending

@CBroe is correct

First get the base path on you live server 
or manually specify the base path like below example

```
$base_directory = '/home/myuser/';
```

then unlink the file that you need to remove.

```
if(unlink($base_directory))
    echo "File has been Deleted.";
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, After trying many ways, I solved storing url info as variable and path with the help of php `substr, strlen` function, I've posted in answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved storing url information as variable and php `substr`, `strlen` function.

```
$img=$_POST['img'];
$len = strlen("http://localhost/uploads/");
$new_path = substr($img, $len, strlen($img)-$len); 
if(unlink($new_path)){
    echo "Deleted";
}
else{
    echo "Fail";
}
```